# Dictionary Splitting/Comprehension

Tags: python, dictionary, dictionary-comprehension

I have a dictionary I want to split into a list of dictionaries for adding submissions into a database.

Here is the dictionary, **this is not a static dict, it would be dynamically generated, so numbers can increase**:

```
# notice the keys are all grouped by numbers, 

 data = {'resident_payer,1': 'William Brown',
        'Term Fee,amount_paid,1': '1',
        'method,1': 'credit',
        'document_id,1': '1',

        'resident_payer,2': None,
        'Term Fee,amount_paid,2': '0',
        'method,2': 'other',
        'document_id,2': '0'}
```

I need a list of dictionaries that would look like this:

```
[
{'resident_payer': 'William Brown', 'Term Fee,amount_paid': '1', 'method': 'credit', 'document_id': '1'},
{'resident_payer': None, 'Term Fee_amount_paid': '0', 'method': 'other', 'document_id': '0'}
]
```

How can I do this in a simple way with a dict comprehension?

Here is working code, but I could not figure the solution out without what seems like strange complexity as I am using and clearing variables declared outside of my loop so I would like a more clear, pythonic way to write this.

```
data = {'resident_payer,1': 'William Brown',
        'Term Fee,amount_paid,1': '1',
        'method,1': 'credit',
        'document_id,1': '1',

        'resident_payer,2': None,
        'Term Fee,amount_paid,2': '0',
        'method,2': 'other',
        'document_id,2': '0'}

# will hold broken down lists
list_of_submissions = list()
# used to parse data into separated list of dictionaries.
# The key is split into numbers for grouping
current_loop = 1
active_dict_to_add_to_list = dict()
for key, value in data.items():
    if f'{current_loop}' in key:
        # we are in the current iteration
        # add the item to the active dict, the key is split by the ',' and [1] is the number so [0] needs to be selected
        # slice by 0: -1 to get first to everything but last element
        key_to_use = ",".join(key.split(',')[0:-1])

        active_dict_to_add_to_list[key_to_use] = value
        print(active_dict_to_add_to_list)
        # I know the dict should be 4 in length s I can realize I need to add here, but I don't like that...
        if len(active_dict_to_add_to_list) == 4:
            list_of_submissions.append(active_dict_to_add_to_list)
            # print('added', active_dict_to_add_to_list)
            active_dict_to_add_to_list = dict()
            current_loop += 1
    else:
        # we need to move to new iteration
        # add the current active dict to the list of submissions
        list_of_submissions.append(active_dict_to_add_to_list)
        print('added', active_dict_to_add_to_list)
        # clear the active dict so it can be added again
        active_dict_to_add_to_list = dict()
        current_loop += 1

print(list_of_submissions)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
data = {'resident_payer,1': 'William Brown',
        'Term Fee,amount_paid,1': '1',
        'method,1': 'credit',
        'document_id,1': '1',

        'resident_payer,2': None,
        'Term Fee,amount_paid,2': '0',
        'method,2': 'other',
        'document_id,2': '0'}

out = {}
for k, v in data.items():
    # all but last element
    key_to_use = ",".join(k.split(',')[0:-1])
    out.setdefault(k.split(',')[-1], {})[key_to_use] = v

out = list(out.values())

print(out)
```

Prints:

```
[{'resident_payer': 'William Brown', 'Term Fee': '1', 'method': 'credit', 'document_id': '1'}, {'resident_payer': None, 'Term Fee': '0', 'method': 'other', 'document_id': '0'}]
```

Comment: I added a change to essentially make `k.split(',')[-1]` turn to `k.split(',')[0:-1]` (I had a logical bug in my initial post when you wrote this answer), but I do not care if you change it yourself, this is a much cleaner solution!

Answer (score 3):

You can make use of [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

```
from itertools import groupby
[{k.split(',')[0]: v for k, v in g} for i, g in groupby(data.items(), key=lambda x: x[0].split(',')[-1])]
```

Result:

```
[{'resident_payer': 'William Brown', 'Term Fee': '1', 'method': 'credit', 'document_id': '1'},
 {'resident_payer': None, 'Term Fee': '0', 'method': 'other', 'document_id': '0'}]
```

Answer (score 2):

This is as far as I can reasonably reduce it:

```
from pprint import pprint

data = {'resident_payer,1': 'William Brown',
        'Term Fee,amount_paid,1': '1',
        'method,1': 'credit',
        'document_id,1': '1',

        'resident_payer,2': None,
        'Term Fee,amount_paid,2': '0',
        'method,2': 'other',
        'document_id,2': '0'}

out1 = {}
for k, v in data.items():
    newk, subid = k.rsplit(",", 1)
    out1.setdefault(subid, {})[newk] = v

out = [out1[k] for k in sorted(out1.keys(), key=int)]

pprint(out)
```

gives:

```
[{'Term Fee,amount_paid': '1',
  'document_id': '1',
  'method': 'credit',
  'resident_payer': 'William Brown'},
 {'Term Fee,amount_paid': '0',
  'document_id': '0',
  'method': 'other',
  'resident_payer': None}]
```

This is assuming that you want the output list sorted in order of the numbers which you used to group the entries by (which were used as keys in the intermediate dictionary `out1`).

Answer (score 0):

try this, `KeyError` break the loop once exhausted with all the index.

```
start_index, parsed_dict = 1, []

keys = ["resident_payer", "Term Fee,amount_paid",
        "Term Fee,amount_paid", "method", "document_id"]

while True:
    try:
        for key in keys:
            parsed_dict.append({key: data[key + "," + str(start_index)]})
    except KeyError:
        break

    start_index += 1

print(parsed_dict)
```

output,

```
[{'resident_payer': 'William Brown'}, {'Term Fee,amount_paid': '1'}, {'Term Fee,amount_paid': '1'}, {'method': 'credit'}, {'document_id': '1'}, 
{'resident_payer': None}, {'Term Fee,amount_paid': '0'}, {'Term Fee,amount_paid': '0'}, {'method': 'other'}, {'document_id': '0'}]
```

Comment: This does not provide the correct output which would make using this data in a group almost impossible as this no longer enables grouped relationships between multiple fields...but it is an interesting approach

Comment: @ViaTech, just to know which case above code will fail ?

Comment: You have a single list of dictionaries with only a single key, value pair. As I say in the post this is a database entry, and there is a grouping with the initial numbers appended to the keys. With the solution you provide,, how is it possible to know which `resident_payer` (or any of the other fields in the grouping) paid which amount?